# Get 4 digit credit card number Authorize.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Hi I had found one sample code where it is asking to pass ApiLoginID, ApiTransactionKey and transactionId.

I am able to get the ApiLoginID and ApiTransactionKey but how do I get the testing transactionID as in testing mode authorize.net always give transactionid as 0

Below is the code through which I need to retrieve the credit card number. please suggest that is this the true code or not to retrieve credit card detail?

```
public class GetTransactionDetails
{
    public static ANetApiResponse Run(String ApiLoginID, String ApiTransactionKey, string transactionId)
  {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        Console.WriteLine("Get transaction details sample");

      ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.RunEnvironment = AuthorizeNet.Environment.SANDBOX;
      // define the merchant information (authentication / transaction id)
      ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.MerchantAuthentication = new merchantAuthenticationType()
      {
          name = ApiLoginID,
          ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.transactionKey,
          Item = ApiTransactionKey,
      };

      var request = new getTransactionDetailsRequest();
      request.transId = transactionId;

      // instantiate the controller that will call the service
      var controller = new getTransactionDetailsController(request);
      controller.Execute();

      // get the response from the service (errors contained if any)
      var response = controller.GetApiResponse();

      if (response != null && response.messages.resultCode == messageTypeEnum.Ok)
      {
          if (response.transaction == null)
              return response;

          Console.WriteLine("Transaction Id: {0}", response.transaction.transId);
          Console.WriteLine("Transaction type: {0}", response.transaction.transactionType);
          Console.WriteLine("Transaction status: {0}", response.transaction.transactionStatus);
          Console.WriteLine("Transaction auth amount: {0}", response.transaction.authAmount);
          Console.WriteLine("Transaction settle amount: {0}", response.transaction.settleAmount);
      }
      else if (response != null)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.messages.message[0].code + "  " +
                            response.messages.message[0].text);
      }

      return response;
   }
 }
}
```

In sample code I am passing below credential

```
const string apiLoginId = "5KP3u95bQpv";
const string transactionKey = "346HZ32z3fP4hTG2";
const string transactionId = "2249735976";
```

where I am retrieving data as below image but nit able to get the creditcard detail

[image]

I just want to retrieve the credit card detail for authorize. Any help

In my code I had also added the code as below but I am receiving error

```
var obj = (creditCardMaskedType)response.transaction.payment.Item;
Console.WriteLine("Creditcard settle cardnumber: {0}", obj.cardNumber);
```

Error

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'AuthorizeNet.Api.Contracts.V1.bankAccountMaskedType' to type 'AuthorizeNet.Api.Contracts.V1.creditCardMaskedType'.

Comment: Are you not able to get the value “0”?

Comment: @theMayer please review updated question

Comment: @theMayer any idea?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do. The thing you're trying to get seems entirely inconsistent with the code you've posted.

Comment: Can you at least link to the part of the example api documentation you are looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last four digits of the credit card are located in the `transaction > payment > creditcard > cardnumber` portion of the response. You should be able to access with `response.transaction.payment.creditCard.cardNumber`.

For your reference, here is a sample response from  `getTransactionDetails` API call. This should show you the structure and better understand how to get to the data you want.

```
{  
   "transaction":{  
      "transId":"2162566217",
      "submitTimeUTC":"2011-09-01T16:30:49.39Z",
      "submitTimeLocal":"2011-09-01T10:30:49.39",
      "transactionType":"authCaptureTransaction",
      "transactionStatus":"settledSuccessfully",
      "responseCode":1,
      "responseReasonCode":1,
      "responseReasonDescription":"Approval",
      "authCode":"JPG9DJ",
      "AVSResponse":"Y",
      "batch":{  
         "batchId":"1221577",
         "settlementTimeUTC":"2011-09-01T16:38:54.52Z",
         "settlementTimeUTCSpecified":true,
         "settlementTimeLocal":"2011-09-01T10:38:54.52",
         "settlementTimeLocalSpecified":true,
         "settlementState":"settledSuccessfully"
      },
      "order":{  
         "invoiceNumber":"60",
         "description":"Auto-charge for Invoice #60"
      },
      "requestedAmountSpecified":false,
      "authAmount":1018.88,
      "settleAmount":1018.88,
      "prepaidBalanceRemainingSpecified":false,
      "taxExempt":false,
      "taxExemptSpecified":true,
      "payment":{  
         "creditCard":{  
            "cardNumber":"XXXX4444",
            "expirationDate":"XXXX",
            "cardType":"MasterCard"
         }
      },
      "customer":{  
         "typeSpecified":false,
         "id":"4"
      },
      "billTo":{  
         "phoneNumber":"(619) 274-0494",
         "firstName":"Matteo",
         "lastName":"Bignotti",
         "address":"625 Broadway\nSuite 1025",
         "city":"San Diego",
         "state":"CA",
         "zip":"92101",
         "country":"United States"
      },
      "recurringBilling":false,
      "recurringBillingSpecified":true,
      "product":"Card Not Present",
      "marketType":"eCommerce"
   },
   "messages":{  
      "resultCode":"Ok",
      "message":[  
         {  
            "code":"I00001",
            "text":"Successful."
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Here you had write the response but what should be the request?
The request would be same as what I have written in the question or it may be different?

Comment: You already have the request correct or else you wouldn't be getting a response.

Comment: My transaction status is coming as declined so it may be because transaction id is not correct. Right?

I need to pass the livemode credential to check actual detail. correct?

Because when I am doing in testing mode I am always receiving transaction id as 0

Comment: Are you using a sandbox account? Or a production account in test mode? There is a difference between the two. In the sandbox you will get a transaction ID when making a test transaction.

Comment: I had created in sandbox but always able to retrieve the transanction id as 0

Comment: I am receiving an error as 'PaymentMaskedType' does not containa definition for 'creditcard' and no extension method 'creditcard' accepting a first argument of type 'PaymentMaskedType' could not be found"  in inserting response.transaction.payment.creditCard.cardNumber.

Comment: I don't use C# so I don't have any sample code to offer

Comment: You get that error because that transACTION WAS AN ach TRANSACTION, NOT A CREDIT CARD TRANSACTION

Comment: Add this line in your answer too

  var obj = (creditCardMaskedType)response.transaction.payment.Item;
                Console.WriteLine("Creditcard number: {0}", obj.cardNumber);
                Console.WriteLine("Creditcard Type: {0}", obj.cardType);
                Console.WriteLine("Creditcard expiration date: {0}", obj.expirationDate);

Comment: Why we are not able to get the expiration month and year? Is it possible to get?

Comment: No, it is not possible to get from this API call. If you use the CIM API you can get the expiration date of a credit card payment created created through that API.

Comment: Can you get me the link for calling cim api?